# Arco Design with Vite and change default Theme parametr

Tags: reactjs, vite

This is part of my vite.config.ts:

```
css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'dashes',
    },
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {},
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          'arco-theme-tag': '.easy-email',
        },
        varsInjectScope: {
          //what to write here?
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

I want to change default Arco Design theme from:

> @arco-theme-tag: body;

into:

> @arco-theme-tag: .easy-email;

But it does not work.
How to do it?